# simple cpp map store and access not working as expected

Tags: c++

I have the following code which uses map to insert Nodes into *mp* according to a *key*. The class has two functions *set* and *get* to insert and access the map respectively.

```
struct Node {
  int value;
  int key;
  Node(int k, int val):key(k),value(val) {};
};

class Cache {
  private:
    map<int, Node*> mp;
    Node* tail;
    Node* head;
  public:
    void set(int, int);
    void get(int);
};

void Cache::set(int key, int value) {
  Node newN = Node(key, value);
  mp.insert(std::pair<int, Node*>(key, &newN));
}

void Cache::get(int key) {
  auto s = this->mp.find(key);
  if (s != this->mp.end()) {
    Node *nHit = s->second;
    std::cout << "Map key = " << s->first;
    std::cout << " : Node Key = " << nHit->key;
    std::cout << ", value = " << nHit->value << "\n";
  }
}
```

A driver main function implementation is below, which takes input of 2 lines and outputs key and value.

```
int main() {
  int i;
  Cache l;
  for(i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    string command;
    cin >> command;
    if(command == "get") {
      int key;
      cin >> key;
      l.get(key);
    }
    else if(command == "set") {
      int key, value;
      cin >> key >> value;
      l.set(key, value);
    }
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

Input -

> set 2 3
>
> get 2

Output -

> Map key = 2 : Node Key = 32764, value = -491659096

Note - The output key and value keeps changing and are not fixed with each run.

Why and how is the key and value getting changed for the map here?

Comment: Why not just `map<int, int>`? The `Node` struct seems superfluous. Or, if you need to use `Node`, maybe`map<int, Node>`?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp It's just a mock code to demonstrate the problem I was facing. The actual scenario requires a struct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to allocate Node using `new`. E.g.,

```
Node *newN = new Node(key, value);
mp.insert(std::pair<int, Node*>(key, newN));
```

As it is your Node is on the stack and goes out of scope when the function returns.

Comment: It's irresponsible to tell a new C++ programmer who's just learning about the stack and block scope to use `new` unless you're going to give them a full explanation of `delete`.

Comment: Just trying to focus on the question that was asked (why is the program failing?)

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting a pointer to a function-scoped value. When the function set() exits the value newN is destroyed, and the pointer held in the map is invalid.

Either you really want a map with an instance of Node as the value; or you need to use new in set() to allocate your object, but then you also need to remember to delete it. You could use "smart" pointers such as shared_ptr or unique_ptr to help manage this lifetime - though unique_ptr won't get you any advantages over using an instance.

Comment: I did not mean to downvote this.  Oops.  This is a good answer.

Comment: I did consider it as a third choice. OK I'll throw it in! Done.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, a piece of data is typically tied to a single location.  If that location is a variable in some `{ block scope; }`, then the variable is deleted at the closing `}`.  For instance, the closing bracket of `Cache::set` deletes `newN`, and any references to it (including pointers in `mp`) no longer point anywhere.

C++ has a second option: the lifetime of some data can be controlled by a class.  For instance, the `int` and `Node*` values you put in `mp` get deleted along with `mp`.  So rather than storing `Node*` in mp, you can store `Node` directly, instead of its address!

The declaration of `mp` should be

```
map<int, Node*> mp;
```

You can insert with

```
void Cache::set(int key, int value) {
  mp.emplace(key, Node(key, value));
}
```

And then in `main` you can have

```
Node &nHit = s->second;
```

And then you can get members of `nHit` with `.` instead of `->`.

---

Your other alternative is to use smart pointers, as Jesper Juhl mentioned.  Store `std::unique_ptr<Node>` in `mp` if you're using pointers only for polymorphism with virtual methods, and `std::shared_ptr<Node>` is useful if you want some of your `Node` objects to be used in several places *and* `mp`.

Taking the address of an object with `&` (e.g. to create `Node*`) is very useful if you want to just reference an object of known lifetime, and you want to store that reference inside of some other object of a shorter lifetime.

DO NOT use `new Node(key, value)` except in a smart pointer constructor, unless you're prepared to individually `delete` *every* `Node*` yourself, and never make mistakes.